# get two datepicker input values using one mounted function with vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to get two input values using one mounted function for the `date picker`. But not getting how do I do that?
Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<div id="app">
<form v-on:submit.prevent="saveFleetJob">
<input type="text" class="fleet-date" v-model="item.from">
<input type="text" class="fleet-date" v-model="item.to">
<button  class="btn btn-primary">Click</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Vue code:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  item: {
                from:'',
                to:''
            },
  },
  mounted() {

        $(".fleet-date").datepicker().on(
            "changeDate", () => {
                this.item.from = $('.fleet-date').val()
            }
        );
   },
  methods: {
    saveFleetJob() {
            alert(JSON.stringify(this.item));
        },
  }
})
```

[js fiddle demo link here](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/293851/)

Any suggestions please?

Comment: check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/293951/). Be careful the context (in the fiddle uses self to save Vue instance, then uses function instead of arrow to get the instance of datepicker); then it is not really a good idea to use JQuery inside Vue like this. it makes the things complicated.

Comment: @Sphinx : Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sphinx pointed there is some context mess, but it's not the only issue.

See this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pb91fk6o/

You have to add

```
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
```

to make this work.

So mounted should look like:

```
  mounted() {
        $(".fleet-date")
        .datepicker()
        .on("changeDate", (e) => {
          e.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('input')) 
        })
   },
```

See this issue for more details: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2804

Comment: @alendroff: Thanks for the help :) and I have used `elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')) ` for select2 dropdown its not working.  [Here is the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pb91fk6o/18/)

Comment: I got it issue with `select2`  plugin. If I remove `select2` resources then its working fine. But how to make it work with `select2` any suggestions please?

Comment: I don't know, to be honest, I'll check it later when I would have more free minutes.

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Comment: @06011991 It seems like you just specified select2 event wrong. Checkout this page https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events ; and this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jbps0wgt/1/

Comment: @Alendroff : Thank you so much for the help :)